# Functional component with hooks results in "cannot read property map of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a classical component and a functional component, they should both do the same thing. 
They both pull data from my API and then should map it to a Div. However, this doesn't work with the functional component and I'd rather use a functional component with hooks.

I've also tried using the "UseLayoutEffect" hook. I know this is happening because the first time the component loads, Games is undefined and it tries to map undefined, but after a tiny delay the API call is finished and Games is now an array of objects. However, it already tried to map undefined. I have a condition 'Games' which should stop it from being mapped if its undefined, but for some reason it passes this condition.

Classical component (working):

```
class Player extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      games: [],
      players: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData()
  }

  async fetchData() {
    const id = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    const games = await axios(`/api/players/${id}`);
    this.setState({ games: games.data });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.games.map((game, i) => (
          <div className="historyId" key={i}>{game.match_id}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Functional component (not-working):
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Player (bundle.js:1422)

```
const Player = (props) => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const [games, setGames] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios(`/api/players/${id}`);
      setGames(response);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
    return (
        <div className="historyContainer">
          <h1>Match history here...</h1>
          {games && games.data.map((game, i) => <div>{game.match_id}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @UncleDave for answering this so quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking if `games` exists but it has a default value (empty object) so it will always exist. You're *not* checking if `games.data` exists - it won't until your HTTP request is completed.

Try this instead:

```
{games.data && games.data.map((game, i) => <div>{game.match_id}</div>)}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. That fixed it. I was trying to figure this out for 4 hours to no avail. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const Player = (props) => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const [games, setGames] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const {data} = await axios(`/api/players/${id}`);
      setGames(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
    return (
        <div className="historyContainer">
          <h1>Match history here...</h1>
          {games.map((game, i) => <div>{game.match_id}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: That still resulted in Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
const {products}=useContext(ProductContext);

const [product, setProduct]=useState();

const getProduct=()=>{
    if(props.match.params.id){
        const res=products;
        const data= res.filter(p=>{
            return p.id === props.match.params.id;
        })
        setProduct(data); 
    }
} 
useEffect(() => {
    getProduct()
},[])

return (
        <div>
            {product && product.map(items=>(
                <div key={items.id}>
                    <h2>{items.name}</h2>
                </div>
                
            ))}
        </div>
)
```

}